# Masonry div height = 0, but should adjust to search results

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, grid, masonry

My content div's height is 0, but I want it to adjust dynamically to its children - which are position absolute. 
I am trying to use masonry as a way to display search results, so sometimes the content div will look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1E8Z.jpg and other times like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F22ED.jpg. How can this be achieved?

I tried using:

```
var biggestHeight = "0";
$("#content *").each(function(){
  if ($(this).height() > biggestHeight ) {
    biggestHeight = $(this).height();
  }
});

$("#content").height(biggestHeight);
```

but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance :)

**css**

```
#wrapper > main > #content{
max-width: 960px;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}

#wrapper > main > #content > article{
position: absolute;
width: 32%;
}
```

**js**

```
function renderGrid(){

var blocks = document.getElementById("content").children;
var pad = 20, cols = 3, newleft, newtop;
for(var i = 1; i < blocks.length; i++){
    if(i % cols == 0){
        newtop = (blocks[i-cols].offsetTop + blocks[i-cols].offsetHeight) + pad;
        blocks[i].style.top = newtop+"px";
        console.log();
    }else{
        if(blocks[i-cols]){ 
            newtop = (blocks[i-cols].offsetTop + blocks[i-cols].offsetHeight) + pad;
            blocks[i].style.top = newtop+"px";
        }
        newleft = (blocks[i-1].offsetLeft + blocks [i-1].offsetWidth) + pad;
        blocks[i].style.left = newleft+"px";
    }
}
}

window.addEventListener("load", renderGrid, false); 
window.addEventListener("resize", renderGrid, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters you could try `overflow: auto` on the content div, but I think that is the default value anyway.

It would be nice to see your html, too.

If you want the content div to be full height all the time (it seems like that would be a good solution) you could use something like

```
#wrapper > main > #content{
     height: 90vh;
}
```

which means 90% of the viewport (the visible part in your browser) height, and set the searchbar to the rest (10% is this example).

Be aware though, that the browser compatibility with that one does not go too far back.

Think about wether you really want to position your items with that function and absolute values. It will not be responsive at all. How to you plan to approach mobile devices?

What you want is either a [css grid](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp) or use flex box. I'd suggest the latter. The browser compatibility of it is really quite good already and flex box really solves all your design problems. It's easy to use and super responsive.

This is a good resource [Solved by FlexBox](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/)